Emitting Angular events overlapping with HTML DOM Events
I had a working code emitting an event like so.
@Output() actChange = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
private emitIds() { ... 
  this.actChange.emit(includedIds); 
}

It was successfully handling the event like this.
<app-child (actChange)="onActChange($event)">

onActChange(input: string[]) {
  console.log('input', input);
  ...
}

Then, I changed it by removing the indicator of acts ending up with this.
@Output() change = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
private emitIds() { ... 
  this.change.emit(includedIds); 
}

<app-child (change)="onChange($event)">

onChange(input: string[]) {
  console.log('input', input);
  ...
}

It still works as supposed to, with a single differece. The method is now invoked twice: once for the previously desired effect, then, once again, for the default event of type Event (the default change of something in the HTML).
I understand what happens and why. However, I have multiple ways to approach it and I'm not certain which to pick. I fear the unexpected, currently obscure, negative implications.
Option 1 is not to use overlapping names for the event.
@Output() actChange = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

Option 2 is to handle the default change by explictly guarding against it.
onChange(input: string[]) {
  console.log('input', input);
  if (input instanceof Event)
    return;
  ...
}

Option 3 would be to turn off the default event being fired (unclear how to, though).
I've googled it and read up on emitting events, suggested style etc. without finding any clear indication of reusing an event's name nor how to deal with it. I've seen a suggestion to prefix but it wasn't a canonical best-practice.
Which of the options above carry zero (or minimal) nagative implications? What other approach would minimize the risks in the future?

TLDR; Option 1 would be the way.


Option #1: Naming convention using named action prefix, ex: actChange


Never use "on" as a prefix.
Here there's an unofficial blog post reference as a best practice. However, you may can consider it as is, because angular/angular-cli codelyzer project added it as a parameter called no-output-named-after-standard-event to handle it from tslint.

Ensures that output bindings, including aliases, are not named as standard DOM events

The rule got migrated to eslint as no-output-native:

An implicit naming convention regarding that feature, would be to name your events as for WHEN they're triggered. In your case, the event is triggered when your "act" is changed, not your whole component.


Option #2: Handling change inside implementation


This option falls into the same pitfall being addressed by codelyzer about Events. Don't name them as any HTML DOM Events.
Also, this approach comes with potencial bugs, as developers have to remember to handle HTML DOM events.


Option #3: Remove HTML DOM event


The change event is not cancellable, so forget about this.

Some notes: I think there's no official documentation regarding this matter, because they just consider it as an implicit rule:

Even angular/components project, straight forward refused to handle the issue.
Also, there was a feature request at angular/angular project to remove the extra event. However, it got old and then closed automatically.


Reading your answer, I realized that I had misinterpreted the "no prefix" point. It's meant to be "no on prefix". And then, it makes a lot of sense. I could prefix by my app name or company code!

As a reflection to the absence of official stand on the subject, I feel disappointed. It seems there's a de facto consensus and an accepted standard approach allowing the default HTML events to come through. That kind of implicit rule says that I should do something but won't explain why. It's better to present a technical reason (or at least to tell that it's opinionated). Anyway, unless an even better answer emerges, I'll assign you the bountaroonis as soon the site will let me.

I consider the feature request link an official POV. I mean, it is angular/angular project. Their stand would be "if you care about this, make an FR and gather enough votes quickly, only then we'll consider it. The current behaviour is not an issue to us"

There is no official documentation about it.
However, known good practice is to never use the Html basic events naming for your custom framework event (it works for any js framework) - knowing the fact that, as they're HTML defined, behavior might be unknown, depending on your framework.
Here is the list of official HTML events: https://www.w3.org/wiki/List_of_events

Yeah, I recon that, surprisingly, there's no official docs on it. Even more surprising is the absence of blogs discussing that matter. I can't be the first in the world to create an event emitter called change or such... While I see the point in the best-practice you suggest (and I'm leaning in that direction in my case), I wonder if you have any reference, link or other material that suggests it. (Otherwise, we're just two dudes who agree on the mutual preference, hehe.)

Also, do you have any idea why I was downvoted (and almost closed) with this question?! I can't see anything but good for and an interesting issue here...

@luiscla answer as more refs, I think it's a better one.
I have absolutely no idea, as it is a very interesting and legitimate question, I found it very usefull (not the case of the question I see often)

Maybe some grumpy user who woke up on the wrong side of the bed. Or, as I suspect often is the case, some arrogant schmuck who deemed the question as "poorly phrased" because they didn't understand the matter (hence assuming it's because of lack of sophistication in it, instead of incompetence on their end). I've heard on occasion something like "your question is bad because Chat GPT didn't give a good answer. Oh boy...)

My guess is that experienced SO users, usually don't like "general basis questions" and this one might be considered as is. So, that kind of questions are usually are downvoted or closed at first by experienced SO users, because "go read docs". But later, they are super upvoted by "low level users" because they tend to get a lot of views. Not the case of this question though.
